# bash: /home/pi/.bashrc: permission denied when setting PATH variable

Tags: java

After having installed Java I want to write some programs. So I did. But when setting PATH variable permanently with command:

`~/.bashrc export PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH`

I get this error:

`bash: /home/pi/.bashrc: Permission denied`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to execute `.bashrc` as a program, which won't work because it's a file and not an executable.

Instead, you need to **add** `export PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH` to `.bashrc`.

One way you can do this is by executing `echo "export PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`, which will append the `export...` command to the end of the `.bashrc` file.